# Python Crash Course (2nd edition) Exercise 9-8

Tags: python

I have a question regarding the solution to Exercise 9-8 in Python Crash Course (2nd edition). The codes are as follows:

```
class User():
    """Represent a simple user profile."""

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, username, email, location):
        """Initialize the user."""
        self.first_name = first_name.title()
        self.last_name = last_name.title()
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.location = location.title()
        self.login_attempts = 0

    def describe_user(self):
        """Display a summary of the user's information."""
        print(f"\n{self.first_name} {self.last_name}")
        print(f"  Username: {self.username}")
        print(f"  Email: {self.email}")
        print(f"  Location: {self.location}")

    def greet_user(self):
        """Display a personalized greeting to the user."""
        print(f"\nWelcome back, {self.username}!")

class Admin(User):
    """A user with administrative privileges."""

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, username, email, location):
        """Initialize the admin."""
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, username, email, location)
        
        # Initialize an empty set of privileges.
        self.privileges = Privileges()


class Privileges():
    """A class to store an admin's privileges."""

    def __init__(self, privileges=[]):
        self.privileges = privileges

    def show_privileges(self):
        print("\nPrivileges:")
        if self.privileges:
            for privilege in self.privileges:
                print(f"- {privilege}")
        else:
            print("- This user has no privileges.")


eric = Admin('eric', 'matthes', 'e_matthes', 'e_matthes@example.com', 'alaska')
eric.describe_user()

eric.privileges.show_privileges()

print("\nAdding privileges...")
eric_privileges = [
    'can reset passwords',
    'can moderate discussions',
    'can suspend accounts',
    ]
eric.privileges.privileges = eric_privileges
eric.privileges.show_privileges()
```

My question is about the second last line. I understand the first "priviledges" refers to the instance in the class Admin. So, what about the second "priviledges"?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: `Admin` objects have an attribute called `privileges` which is a `Privileges` object which in turn has a `privileges` attribute which is a list... So, `eric.privileges.privileges` accesses the privileges list

Comment: To be honest, the whole `Privileges` class is redundant and can be removed. Simply save the `privileges` list directly under `Admin` and add `show_privileges` as an `Admin` method or even just an external function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, it's because `Admin` contains `self.privileges = Privileges()`, then the `Privileges` class contains `self.privileges = privileges` again.

I don't know why they've set it up like this though. The code is a tad sketchy. The `Privileges` class alone has multiple odd things:

- You don't need the `()` in `class Privileges():`.
- `privileges=[]` is [nearly always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument). Never have a mutable default argument.
- Why even have the class? All it's doing is housing a method. That method could easily be a method of `Admin`, or as a standalone function that accepts `admin.privileges` as an argument. It isn't encapsulating anything, so it's really just making the code more complex than it needs to be.

I'd be cautious taking advice from this source.

Comment: Just that `privileges=[]` alone is a huge red flag. I can't believe any tutorial teaching people Python would put that out there, let alone anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The class Admin has an attribute self.privileges that is an object of the class Privileges. The class Privileges also has an attribute named self.privileges.

class Admin, attribute privileges -> class Privileges, attribute privileges
`eric.privileges.privileges = eric_privileges`

Answer (score -1):

```
class Privileges():
    """A class to store an admin's privileges."""

    def __init__(self, privileges=[]):
        self.privileges = privileges
```

not sure why but was thinking about this line of code,

adding this at the end of the file

```
print('***************')
for property, value in vars(eric).items():
    print(property, ":", value)
print('***************')

print(type(eric.privileges))
print(eric.privileges)
print('id : ',id(eric.privileges))
for property, value in vars(eric.privileges).items():
    print(property, ":", value)
print('***************')
print(type(eric.privileges.privileges))
print(eric.privileges.privileges)
print('id : ',id(eric.privileges.privileges))
```

gives :

```
***************
first_name : Eric
last_name : Matthes
username : e_matthes
email : e_matthes@example.com
location : Alaska
login_attempts : 0
privileges : <__main__.Privileges object at 0x7fd795456be0>
***************
<class '__main__.Privileges'>
<__main__.Privileges object at 0x7fd795456be0>
id :  140563899050976
privileges : ['can reset passwords', 'can moderate discussions', 'can suspend accounts']
***************
<class 'list'>
['can reset passwords', 'can moderate discussions', 'can suspend accounts']
id :  140563932329856
```

guess  these two privileges are related but slightly different

As per answer one :
as in one: The class Admin has an attribute self.privileges that is an object of the class Privileges. The class Privileges also has an attribute named self.privileges. class Admin, attribute privileges -> class Privileges, attribute privileges eric.privileges.privileges = eric_privileges

Comment: In what way does this answer the question?

Comment: as in one: 

The class Admin has an attribute self.privileges that is an object of the class Privileges. The class Privileges also has an attribute named self.privileges.

class Admin, attribute privileges -> class Privileges, attribute privileges
eric.privileges.privileges = eric_privileges ??

Comment: all the above should be [edit]ed into your answer... That's the actual answer. Simply posting the exact same code from the question is not an answer. The whole point of the question is that the OP do not understand that code

Comment: I will revert it once you edited your answer... A ban is not an excuse to post low-quality content...

Comment: Why don't you put your first comment above in the answer? That's exactly the answer to the question...

Comment: Look at the other answers and my comments under the question. It's just a (not necessary if you ask me) 2-level capsulation: the admin has a privileges object which has a list of privileges

Comment: I’ll do as soon as I figure out the entire picture. Tried online  http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit  on the script but wasn’t really helpful.

Comment: So ‘#Initialize an empty set of privileges’ in the code its kind of misleading ? Or it’s the right way to describe:  self.privileges = Privileges() ??

Comment: Yes I agree. It can be misleading. It should be something more like *initialize a new privileges object with an empty list of privileges*

Comment: set() list object too much too soon to me nevetheless thanks a lot